# Products wont add to cart from most pages

Tags: magento, cart

I can add to cart from my featured products on my front page.  But I can't add to cart anywhere else.  Clicking "add to cart" from any category or product itself just put me in the cart where it says "your cart is empty"

its not a theme thing, problem happens with default or my theme

my site is luvnailz.com/shop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score -1):

What version of Magento are you using? For newer versions of Magento you need to include a "form key" when adding products to cart.

This could be missing if you installed an extension which did not include it and may still be enabled even though you switched theme.

You can try and go to Dashboard>System>Configuration>Advanced and disable any extension that you have installed and see if it now works. You can always enable again afterwards.

Please provide your Magento version number (Is in the bottom of backend, when logged in)

/Skaug